# Operator.report not showing up in header

Tags: python, scripting

```
class my_operator(bpy.types.Operator)
    bl_idname = "op.my_custom_operator"
    bl_label = "my_custom_operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls,context):
        return True

    def execute(self,context):
        return self.invoke(context,None)

    def invoke(self,context,event):
       ... do some code here...
       self.report({'INFO'},"MESSAGE OF SOME SORT")
```

The above is a representation of what my code looks like - it executes fine, the only problem seems to be that whatever I use self.report with, the resulting message never appears in blender's header, as it should according to the documentation and every topic I've found on the subject ( I have looked around and found nothing that helps me ). Instead, the output refuses to go anywhere but the console window.

Does anyone know a way to get information to Blender's header?

Comment: the reason I'm doing it like that is because I'm using this operator as a handler for a post save event, through a separate method. I could try and put the code under execute and leave out invoke entirely, and see if that works. functionally there's not really a reason for me to do have it, other than that the only example I've found using an operator as a handler used it that way.